# cant Parse Date in windows 10

Tags: c#

I have  code like belowe :

```
set
        {
            iDate = (DateTime.Parse(value).ToPersianDateString());
        }
```

`ToPersianDateString` is a Extension method to convert `2016` to `1395` e.x.

this code work very well but in windows 10, below code , retrun an exception

```
DateTime.Parse(value)
```

my value is : `Aug 31 2016 12:00AM`

Exception message is : `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`
why it return error ?

I think problem is `Aug` .

Comment: Check if it accepts `.` instead of `:`.

Comment: You need to use `ParseExact` and pass the format as `"MMM dd yyyy hh:mmtt"`

Comment: I think my question is not duplicate because my code doesnt work just in windows 10 , that question was asked 7 years ago

Comment: Check if this article applies to your problem: http://www.heikniemi.net/hardcoded/2015/08/windows-10-breaks-net-date-parsing-in-certain-locales/

Comment: @osmanRahimi It has nothing to do with windows 10. It has to do with explicitly specifying the format and the culture.

Comment: @osmanRahimi `var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "MMM dd yyyy hh:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` works perfectly on windows 10 ! I have just tried it.

Comment: @user3185569 thanks a lot , yes it  works well